# How can I create dynamic menu in Mono for Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to make dynamic menu with Mono for Android ,I have table menu in SQLLite data base;
how can I add menu item to my menu from that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override dispatchKeyEvent(), like so:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
    ...
    return true;
```